# When is a MySQL MDL blocking? When can something time out waiting for it?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently looking into setting the `lock_wait_timeout` setting for my DB to something short, like 5 seconds, and want to evaluate the safety of this decision.

My understanding is that for normal DML, the shared MDL is acquired. However, when a DDL operation wants to commit, it acquires the exclusive MDL, for which it will wait for the shared MDL to release (and block all other queries). In this case, it may timeout, as well as the queries waiting for the DDL to complete.

Am I missing any other cases in which an operation may time out waiting for the MDL? Are there any glaring risks to setting this variable to something short for the entire DB?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve and why do you want to change the setting?

Comment: I am trying to protect the database from DDLs waiting on metadata locks (probably from unclosed transactions), that in turn block all queries. While in an ideal world we identify and resolve all the potential unclosed transactions, this is a company-wide monolithic database and there are thousands of potential locations where this can happen. We had an incident recently where this blocked writes for a period of time.

Comment: This will not solve your problem, it will just turn it into another problem.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how so?

Comment: I think obviously the goal is to eliminate the cause (uncommitted transactions), but I think it's good to have a temporary guardrail, as well as futureproof future uncommited transactions from causing issues.